# XUL/Firefox Extension: Determine scroll position of main window

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm developing firefox sidebar that interacts with the main browser window. When a button within the sidebar is clicked, I need to be able to determine how far down the current page the user has scrolled.

Anybody have any ideas? I can't seem to find the right combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for anyone else that may be looking for it:

```
window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
  .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
  .rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow)
  .gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.scrollY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the **scrollTop** and **scrollHeight** attributes should help you. You can combine it with the **clientHeight** attribute.

Pseudo code :

```
scrollPercent = 100
if(clientHeight <= scrollHeight) {
    scrollPercent = (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100
}
```

Comment: The following will return me the client height fine:

window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
  .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
  .rootTreeItem
  .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow)
  .gBrowser.selectedBrowser.clientHeight

However calling scrollHeight on the same object always returns a value equal to clientHeight, and calling scrollTop always returns 0.

Apologies for the formatting :/